# Using information from an Array (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Building an angularjs app I am looping through some JSON data to pull out specific data from a nested array.

At the moment I am searching through that data and pushing what I want in to an array and then returning that array.

However I would like a bit more control over the data instead of just spitting it out as a basic string. So at the moment my code is:

```
$scope.actionType = function(event) {
        var myArray = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < player.skills.length; j++){
          var obj = event.keywords[j];
          if (obj.type === 'PASSING'){
            myArray.unshift(obj.value);
          }
          if (obj.type === 'HEADING'){
            myArray.push(obj.value);
          }
          if (obj.type === 'GOALS'){
            if (obj.value === 'GOALNUMBER'){
               myArray.push(obj.value);
            }
            else{  myArray.push(obj.value); }
          }
          if (obj.type === 'PLAYER'){
            myArray.push(obj.value);
            player = obj.value;
          }

        }
        console.log(myArray);
        var joinArray = myArray.join(' - ');
        return joinArray;
      };
```

I'm starting to get a bit out of my depth now and i'm not sure the best way to go about it... I was thinking maybe I could assign the hits different variables and then building that up in to a complete bit of code, or maybe build them up through ng-if's in the front end. I'm just not sure what is the 'right' or 'best' way to go about it.

Any advice much appreciated as always!

Edit:

I have looked in to adding variables to the scope in the controller and assigning them in the same way i pushed them to the array. This means I can now access them from my template inside my controller with {{ xyz }}. 
Now I just have to figure out how to assign images when certain conditions are meet! Gulp!

Comment: So you want to filter the array by type ?

Comment: How about an example of your desired input and output.

Comment: so at the moment i get a basic output of: Peter - 7 for e.g. Ideally I would prefer to have a lot more html control for something in the front end like: <span>{{ Name }}</span> - <span>{{ passing }}</span> - <span>{{Goals}}</span> (obviously they would be wrapped around ng-ifs to check if they weren't empty.